# Am I resetting the computational graph completely in my tensorflow code?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to do some experimentation. 
After every minibatch I am trying to restructure the computational graph. 
I have a feeling though that there are some issues. When I plant initial values for W1,W2,W3, for the first minibatch i get updates I expect. I however do not get the updates I expect starting on the second minibatch.  Is there perhaps to check what the computational graph looks like at each iteration?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
bsize = 5
Xset = np.random.uniform(0,1,(60000,6*20)) * 50
Yset = Xset[:,0]

Wone = np.random.normal(0, .35, (6,6))
Wtwo = np.random.normal(0, .35, (6,6))
Wthree = np.random.normal(0, .35, (6,6))

Results = []

for q in range(1):
    for k in range(40):
        from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
        ops.reset_default_graph()
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        tf.InteractiveSession()
        x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(bsize,6*20))
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(bsize,1))
        x = tf.reshape(x1,[bsize,6,20])
        InitialState = tf.zeros((6,bsize))
        h = InitialState
        W1 = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(Wone,dtype = tf.float32),name = "W1")
        W2 = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(Wtwo,dtype = tf.float32),name = "W2")
        W3 = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(Wthree,dtype = tf.float32),name = "W3")


#create list
        lis = []
        for q in range(10):
            pit = np.random.uniform(-1,1)
            #print pit

            if(pit<0) or q == 0 or pit==0 or pit > 0:
                lis.append(q)

        for p in lis:
            h = tf.matmul(W1,h) + tf.matmul(W2,tf.transpose(x[:,:,p]))
            h = tf.nn.relu(h)

        hstar = h
        output = tf.matmul(W3,hstar)
        output1 = output[0:1,:]

        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(tf.transpose(output1) ,y)*tf.sub(tf.transpose(output1) ,y))

        opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        opt_operation = opt.minimize(loss)

        for h in range(1):
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
                a,b,RLoss,_ = sess.run([hstar,output,loss,opt_operation], feed_dict = {x1:Xset[(bsize*k):(bsize*k+bsize),:],y:Yset[bsize*k:k*bsize+bsize,None]})

                print RLoss, k
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `tf.reset_default_graph()` is sufficient. You can see what your graph looks like by inspecting `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` which is a protobuf of `tensorflow.GraphDef` schema implemented [here](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto#15)

In particular, to get all names of nodes in the graph, you can do

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

Comment: Thank you! There is another thing I was wondering if you might be able to answer Yaroslav. When creating highly custom and repeating computational graphs, it would often be useful to have custom functions that can easily istantiate a portion of graph. So far I have been basically creating these computational graphs in basically a script. Do you know if we can create functions which can help us create portions of the graph?  Best

Comment: Yes, there are functions although I don't have experience with them. There are examples of usage in [python/framework/function_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/function_test.py)